# How is the XML syntax for adding a multi value field to a SOLR 3 Server

Tags: xml, api, rest, solr

I guess this is an easy question but I seem to be unable to find it in the documentation or the Solr wiki.

So, I just need to know how the syntax for adding a multi value field (arr) is.

I know you can add any other field like

```
<add>
 <doc>
  <field name="fieldname">fieldvalue</field>
 </doc>
</add>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at some of the example documents that come with Solr, you can just define the same field with multiple values in the xml.

So you could do the following

```
 <add>
  <doc>
   <field name="fieldname">fieldvalue</field>
   <field name="category">value1</field>
   <field name="category">value2</field>
  </doc>
 </add>
```

See the examples here - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/example/exampledocs/